# Como matar processos com o Delphi?

Tags: delphi, processo

Preciso fazer uma aplicação em Delphi que finalize processos através do nome de imagem, se isto for possível me diga como.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use esta função:

```
   function KillTask(ExeFileName: string): Integer;
    const
      PROCESS_TERMINATE = $0001;
    var
      ContinueLoop: BOOL;
      FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
      FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
    begin
      Result := 0;
      FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
      FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
      ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
      while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
      begin
        if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) =
          UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) =
          UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
          Result := Integer(TerminateProcess(
                            OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,
                                        BOOL(0),
                                        FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID),
                                        0));
         ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
      end;
      CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
    end;
```

Para usar:

```
  KillTask('calc.exe');
```

> Declare: TLHelp32

Comment: Deve estar faltando alguma declaração, pois o Delphi está encontrando erros.

Comment: Declare: TLHelp32. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Olá!

Eu estava precisando finalizar um processo pelo seu PID. Por exemplo, se eu tivesse duas planilhas MS Excel abertas, eu gostaria de finalizar apenas uma delas, específica pelo PID.

No gerenciador de tarefas:

> MSEXCEL 8345
>
> MSEXCEL 9601   <- esse é o relacionado à minha aplicação

Para encerrar, por exemplo, apenas o processo PID 9601, utilizei algo como:

```
var planilha: OleVariant; ProcIdXL: cardinal; xlHWND: HWND; sucesso: boolean;
begin
  planilha := CreateoleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
  // armazena informação do processo
  xlHWND := planilha.hwnd;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(xlHWND, ProcIdXL);  // vai pegar o 9601
  ...
  // executa o meu código
  sucesso := true;
  ...
  finally
  ...      
  if (not sucesso) AND (not VarIsEmpty(planilha)) then begin
    planilha := Unassigned;
    if (ProcIdXL > 0) then
      TerminateProcess(OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, BOOL(0), ProcIdXL), 0);
    end;
  ...
  end;
end;
```

Basta adaptar à sua necessidade...