# Como finalizar o processo do próprio executável com o Delphi?

Tags: delphi, processo

Já postei numa thread aqui no overflow sobre um problema que estou tendo com o componente TWebBrowser, quando uso ele a aplicação não finaliza, fica na lista de processos do windows é como se ele ficasse esperando a liberação do componente ActiveX, mas não gera nenhum erro, então fica dificil de achar o problema, já segui algumas dicas do colegas, mas sem sucesso, isso acontece em algumas máquinas somente.

Preciso resolver esse problema mesmo que paliativamente então pensei em finalizar o processo depois de dar um Application.Terminate, o detalhe é que não sei se isso é possível e o comando pra isso no  Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garimpando na web acabei por encontrar uma função no próprio stackoverflow que resolveu meu problema, segue o link [Como matar processos com o Delphi?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88611/como-matar-processos-com-o-delphi)